How to prove that:$\lim _{a \rightarrow 0} \int_0^{+\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-a x} f(x) \mathrm{d} x=\int_0^{+\infty} f(x) \mathrm{d} x$
Suppose that $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable on $[0, \infty)$ and the improper integral $\int_0^{+\infty} f(x) \mathrm{d} x$ converges. Prove that:
$$
\lim _{a \rightarrow 0} \int_0^{+\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-a x} f(x) \mathrm{d} x=\int_0^{+\infty} f(x) \mathrm{d} x
$$
MY TRY:Since $\int_0^{+\infty} f(x) \mathrm{d} x$ converges,
when $a \geqslant 0$ and $x \geqslant 0$, we have $\left|e^{-a x}\right| \leq 1$.
By Abel's Test, we know that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& I(a)=\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-a x} f(x) \mathrm{d} x, \text { converges uniformly } \\
& \lim _{a \rightarrow 0^{+}} \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-a x} f(x) \mathrm{d} x=\int_0^{+\infty} \lim _{a \rightarrow 0^{+}} e^{-a x} f(x) \mathrm{d} x=\int_0^{+\infty} f(x) \mathrm{d} x
\end{aligned}
$$
How should we handle the case when $a<0$, that is, $\lim _{a \rightarrow 0^{-}} \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-a x} f(x) \mathrm{d} x$ ?

$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax} f(x) dx$ may diverge for $a < 0$ under the given conditions.

Yeah, an easy example would be $f(x)=e^{-x}$. The statement should only have $a \to 0^+$.

Or $f(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$. Then $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax} f(x) dx$ diverges for any $a < 0$.

Under the conditions of your porblem you do have that $\lim_{a\rightarrow0+}\int^\infty_0 e^{-ax}f(x),dx=\int^\infty_0 f(x),dx)$. Here is a proof in MSE.

See Wikipedia. This is the Final Value Theorem for improperly integrable functions (Abel's theorem for integrals)
